# Boot Raspberry Pi 4 from USB

Tags: usb, boot, sd-card, pi-4

I have tried to boot a Raspberry Pi 4 from an SD card, and it is working fine. But when I was trying to boot the Raspberry Pi 4 from USB, it was not booting up.

Is it possible to boot the Raspberry Pi 4 from USB without using an SD card?

Answer (score 4):

No, that's not been implemented yet. The Raspberry Pi 4 has a different boot process to earlier Raspberry Pis. You can still put your root file system on the USB drive and point the SD card to it which is what I do:

*[Raspberry Pi 4 USB Boot Config Guide for SSD / Flash Drives](https://jamesachambers.com/raspberry-pi-4-usb-boot-config-guide-for-ssd-flash-drives/)*

Comment: *"The guy with the Swiss accent"* also covered it (15 minutes long): *[Boot a Raspberry Pi4 with an SSD to make it reliable and fast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gp6XW-fGVjo)*

Comment: love the guy with the swiss accent - his tutorials or links to tutorials never fail

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can boot from the raspberry pi now. Everything you need to know is in this article [How to Boot Raspberry Pi 4 From a USB SSD or Flash Drive](http://rebrand.ly/9n6itr8)You enter a few commands and change some configuration settings copy the sd card and then reboot the raspberry pi.