# Does Raspberry Pi 4 support boot medium other than SD card

Tags: boot, sd-card

Does Raspberry Pi 4 support boot medium other than SD card.
Can I boot raspberry Pi from EMMC or NOR flash ?

Thanks,
Swapnil

Comment: What happens if you google the question?

Comment: That answer is literally one Google away from you. Even in here https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109546/boot-raspberry-pi-4-from-usb there are answers.

Answer (score 0):

Other than SD card, It is possible to boot Raspberry Pi from USB.

Some Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 (CM4) boards come with a built-in eMMC flash chip for storing nonvolatile data. This chip replaces the need for a separate SD card, which can be useful if you want to save space on your expansion board or don’t want the user to flash an SD card.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. SD card is not considered reliable in industrial environment. Same goes for USB. Basically I wish to know whether it is possible to configure an EMMC as boot medium.  Any thoughts/information you have regarding this?

Comment: I am looking for Raspberry PI 4 board only. I did google and mostly saw that SD Card, USB is mentioned. But I am looking to see if anybody has used EMMC or any other boot medium which is considered reliable for industrial use.